# redux state in componentWillRecieveProps issue with forward and back button

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have problem showing an alert dialog using redux. I want to show a success message after user has edited says a form. I set a flag through action > reducer > store.

Then I do

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if(nextProps.data.updated_form) {
      alert('form has been updated!');
    }
}
```

There's problem in this approach. User updated the form, then he click somewhere to go to other route, then he click back to my form, that alert will trigger too.

Comment: Why retrigger alert is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your existing solution is that `updated_form` variable of the store doesn't change over time. So getting back to the page retriggers the alert. One simple solution would be to create another action creator to reset those changes on componentWillUnmount()`.

sample store reducer could like this

```
case 'RESET_CHANGES':
    return {...state,updated_form:null}
```

And the react component will have similar code like this

```
componentWillUnmount() {
     this.props.resetChanges() // assuming you have created action creator
}
```

Comment: Is this how one should do for success or error message? I've not seen this pattern in many source code. But this approach does make sense.

Comment: as you are using redux store for your alert messaging stuff, i've told this way you could achieve your goals. If I were to work on this project, I'd not bloated redux store for alert stuff, would be using react state in the component

Comment: yeah I'm using redux. I throw every state to the store.